# Can a topological vector space be probabilistic metric space too?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, probability-distributions

Is it possible to have probabilistic metric space (S,F,T) be a topological vector space too?
In specific way, the probabilistic metric space is Menger and does not have a norm, however with Menger space we know that a probabilistic metric exists which  may redefined the properties of TVS (absolutely convex, absorbing, ... ) with the  probabilistic metric induced by Menger space.

Comment: This question is very poorly formulated. *Obviously* a set of continuum cardinality can bear a TVS structure in an infinite variety of ways, and can bear a probabilistic metric space structure in an infinite variety of ways. Do you want particular relations to hold between the two types of structure?

Comment: I see some votes to close the question. I think that those votes were cast a little bit too quickly. I would recommend that we wait at least a couple of hours to let the OP reformulate their question, as suggested by Todd Trimble.

Comment: the question makes sense if TVS does not admit a norm  .

Comment: @AndréHenriques ... "wait a couple of hours" ... done ... but putting it "on hold" will keep the problem here until the OP comes back to explain.  Since it is the weekend, it may take 2 or 3 days.  Maybe he should include a reference like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_metric_space to explain what is a probabilistic metric space.

Comment: Probabilistic metric space is quite different by probability space. Specially menger space has widely investigated due to it apllication in fixed point theory. So i guess you assume you want to make or redefine TVS by induced t-norm?

Comment: I sugguest not to close since with new revision, the question looks clear